# Codeigniter csrf expired token

Tags: codeigniter

In my codeigniter ajax application, if a user's session has timed out and they submit an ajax form, since the csrf token has expired, the server returns a 500 error... how do I have the server return a 401 error instead so I can at least process the error and redirect the user to the login form?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Output class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/output.html). From the User Guide:

> #### $this->output->set_status_header(code, 'text');
>
> Permits you to manually set a server status header. Example:

```
$this->output->set_status_header('401');
// Sets the header as: Unauthorized
```

I was about to suggest extending the Security class and overwriting the function that generates the CSRF error:

```
/**
 * Show CSRF Error
 *
 * @return  void
 */
public function csrf_show_error()
{
    //show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.');

    // Set 401 header instead of the default 500
    show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.', 401);
}
```

...but this won't always be correct - And most importantly, I don't think you need to do this when the token is submitted. You should already have sent the unauthorized header *before* the token was even validated.

From your comment:

> It's not that the csrf token and the session are directly related but the default expiration of both are the same. So if the user hasn't refreshed their browser in a while, and then refreshes the page, CI will renew the session and the csrf token.... but with ajax, since it cant refresh the token, it just returns the 500 error.

If this is the only thing preventing you from validating the session before the CSRF token, try setting the session token to expire 10 seconds earlier than the token. If the request is unauthorized, there's no point in validating the token to begin with.

Comment: I tried this with standard php headers, but it seems that before my controller's construct is even called the error is being returned.

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't actually aware that the token was validated so early in CI execution. have you tried hard-coding it into the `csrf_show_error()` function in `system/Security.php` to make sure that it works otherwise?

Comment: So I just tried creating a MY_Output.php in the core folder and placing the 401 header in the construct, and it does seem to send the header correctly before the csrf validation... but this really doesn't help since it's outside of the scope of my controller and I can't seem to find a variable to use in a conditional to set a header... and it just feels like a hack anyways.

Comment: csrf_show_error() seems to just set the error message but not the headers.

Comment: I'm stumped on how to do this properly, the token is validated when the Security class is constructed. I'm still wondering how the token expiring is related to the session timing out = the token should still be valid because it has nothing to do with the session, am I missing something?

Comment: It's not that the csrf token and the session are directly related but the default expiration of both are the same.  So if the user hasn't refreshed their browser in a while, and then refreshes the page, CI will renew the session and the csrf token.... but with ajax, since it cant refresh the token, it just returns the 500 error.

Comment: My mistake, it's actually called when the Input class is constructed, in the function `_sanitize_globals()` - it's the only place `csrf_verify()` is ever called. Hope that helps, I updated my answer but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Actually Im realizing the problem here: CI validates the CSRF token first. What I want is to see if the users session is even active before processing an ajax request, but CI shoots off a csrf error before I can even get there. The order is backwards.